# Android chromecast video-cast from sd-card or internal storage

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, chromecast, google-cast

I want to implement video-cast of video from internal storage or sd-card.

I see that this [sample](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) (https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android ) does cast of internet content only.

How can I do same thing but using video from device ??
There is some tutorial or sample code ?

**Edit:**
I do more search, local web server is the way ? Something like nanohttpd ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set up a local web server in your android app and serve the media from that server.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you know a way for casting rtsp live video streams ? I read that rtsp is not supported from Chromecast.

Answer (score 0):

step 1:
Run simple http server app in your device
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ubi.common.http.server&hl=en

step 2: open chrome in your laptop and type your android device's http address (from the above app). you will get your device's directory. copy the address of a video file.

step 3. in CastVideos-android project open VideoProvider.java file.
modify the line :
String videoUrl =

step4: run the CastVideos-android project and enjoy casting.
(try clicking on big buck bunny video, to get the video casted faster)